# how to encrypt a text using RSA in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rsa

I am trying to encrypt username and password using RSA algorithm in iphone app. i came across seckeyref from security framework in iphone. but i do not know how to give input public key of the type seckeyref.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157) lists all the functions you may need.

Comment: This is not a guide but a reference.